# How angular promise .then works

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am new to AngularJS $q and promise, I learn that if I use `$http.get()`, I can get a promise and I can use its `.then` function chainly like

```
$http.get(url)
     .then(function(data){}, function(err){})
     .then(function(data){}, function(err){})
     .....
```

Each then return a new promise, but my question is how do I know that then has been resolved? One thing I notice is if I add return to the `function(data){}`, the next then function can get that return value from previous then function, so does that mean I need give a return as resolve?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I know that then has been resolved?

As you noticed, the promise returned by `then()` is resolved after the callback is executed (which is executed when the first promise is fulfilled). And it does resolve with the result from the callback indeed.

> Do I need give a return as resolve?

No, if you don't `return` anything from the callback, the result is `undefined` - just like with regular function calls.

However, you do in fact have more options to build a result in your callback than returning a plain value:

- You can `return` another promise. The promise returned by `then()` will adopt it, i.e. fulfills with its result or reject with its reason as soon as it settles.
- You can `throw` an exception. It will get automatically caught and the resulting promise is rejected with that error.

Answer (score 0):

The initial promise has been resolved when the callback of the first `then` executes, but you can chain `thens` like you described.
Each `then` invocation creates a new derived promise. If you return a concrete value from a `then` callback the derived promise will be resolved with that value. You will be able to access that value as an argument in the subsequent `then` callback

```
serviceCall().then(function(){})//nothing returned => resolves with undefined value
             .then(function(){return 10;})//will resolves with the value 10
             .then(function(data){//data is 10 here
              });
```

Basically there is no need to manually resolve promises. You can also call external functions that return promises like other $http requests as well.

```
serviceCall().then(function(){
  return $http.get('/get-customer-from-server');//returns customer
})
.then(function(customer){
  //the customer is available here
})
```

For brevity I was omitting the error callback. The error callback will execute if any of the promises were rejected, which is likely to be due to a failure somewhere. There is a short hand notation for error handling. Instead of a then with two callbacks you can use `catch`

```
serviceCall().then(function(){
})
.catch(function(){//error handling if promise was rejected
})
```

catch is an alias for `.then(null,function(){});`

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained